# How do I prove these equations? transform three ratios added up, into three proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$\frac{l}{({\sqrt a} - {\sqrt b})} + \frac{m}{({\sqrt b} - {\sqrt c})} + \frac{n}{({\sqrt c} - {\sqrt a})} = {0}$$
and
$$\frac{l}{({\sqrt a} + {\sqrt b})} + \frac{m}{({\sqrt b} + {\sqrt c})} + \frac{n}{({\sqrt c} + {\sqrt a})} = {0}$$

show that

$$\frac{l}{(a - b)(c - {\sqrt ab})} = \frac{m}{(b - c)(a - {\sqrt bc})} = \frac{n}{(c - a)(b - {\sqrt ac})}$$

I have no clue where to even start, sorry. Somehow you need to separate the first 6 formula's? Even more detailed steps where to go next would be appreciated, no need to spell out how to do the steps. As long as i know the method.

Thanks.

Comment: I would try to use the last equalities to substitute  for each numerator on the first two equations.

Comment: **HINT**: Multiply the first equation by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ and the second equation by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}$. If you then subtract both equations then the terms with $l$ should cancel out. Simplify the resulting equation in $m$ and $n$ to get part of the solution. Repeat this process to cancel $m$ and you should end up with the desired result.

Comment: Im stuck at this point, I got $$m/({\sqrt ab} +b -...) + m/({\sqrt ab} - b...) -n/({\sqrt ac} - {\sqrt bc}...) - n/({\sqrt ac} + {\sqrt bc}...) = 0$$ . 

I have no idea how to get the next step here. When I get n to the other side, and try to cross multiply both sides, it becomes a big mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sqrt make it inconvenience so I use 
$$\frac{l}{a-b}+\frac{m}{b-c}+\frac{n}{c-a}=0=\frac{l}{a^2-b^2}+\frac{m}{(b-c)(a+b)}+\frac{n}{(c-a)(a+b)}\\
\frac{l}{a+b}+\frac{m}{b+c}+\frac{n}{c+a}=0=\frac{l}{a^2-b^2}+\frac{m}{(b+c)(a-b)}+\frac{n}{(c+a)(a-b)}$$ 
which will give a relation between m and n
$$\frac{m}{(b-c)(a+b)}+\frac{n}{(c-a)(a+b)}=\frac{m}{(b+c)(a-b)}+\frac{n}{(c+a)(a-b)}\\
\frac{m((b+c)(a-b)-(b-c)(a+b)}{(b^2-c^2)(a^2-b^2)}=\frac{n((c-a)(a+b)-(c+a)(a-b))}{(c^2-a^2)(a^2-b^2)}\\
\frac{m(ac-b^2)}{(b^2-c^2)(a^2-b^2)}=\frac{n(bc-a^2)}{(c^2-a^2)(a^2-b^2)}\\\frac{m((b+c)(a-b)-(b-c)(a+b)}{(b^2-c^2)(a^2-b^2)}=\frac{n((c-a)(a+b)-(c+a)(a-b))}{(c^2-a^2)(a^2-b^2)}\\
\frac{m}{(b^2-c^2)(bc-a^2)}=\frac{n}{(c^2-a^2)(ac-b^2)}$$ Which gives the 2nd equation. The first equation can be obtained by $l\to m\to n \to l$, $a\to b\to c \to a$, Hope it can help.